# How to display line number while doing grep on a file

Tags: command-line, grep

How to display line number while doing grep on a file. For example:

```
grep CONFIG_PM_ADVANCED_DEBUG /boot/config-`uname -r
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is the option `-n`, and many more in the manual page, worth reading.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that using `-n` with `-l` does not work. `-l` will take precedence and only the name of the file will be printed.

Comment: An example in the answer would be helpful!

Answer (score 10):

`grep -n <pattern> <file>` prefixes each line of output with the line number in the input file. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: mid-air collision with enzotib, who was faster

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `cat -n 'filename'`. This will print the line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`alias grep='grep -inE --color=auto'`

This will color the match as well for easy reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat -n /boot/config | grep CONFIG_PM_ADVANCED_DEBUG
```

`cat` will `-n[umber]` the lines and `| (filter)` through `grep` looking only for lines with `CONFIG_PM....` in them

the resulting output will be line number; the text of the line and the string

```
cat -n[umber lines] /Path/to/filename | grep -i[gnor case (optional)] STRING_TO_LOOK_FOR
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. I edited your post, so it utilizes the formatting possibilities of the site a bit more. Please review the changes (with the edit history), so your future answers (and questions) might look better. It is also not necessary to "sign" your post, your name is posted with your profile on all answers